# Turn Vim windows on the side

Tags: vim-windows

Let's say I have two windows open, stacked one above the other (via `vim -o file1 file2` or `:split`).

Is there a command (sequence) which would allow me to turn this into two windows that are *side by side* (as via `vim -O file1 file2` or `:vsplit`)?

More generally speaking, is there a command (sequence) to turn the currently displayed windows on the side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move one of the windows to the side, with [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_H) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>:

```
                                                CTRL-W_H
CTRL-W H        Move the current window to be at the far left, using the
                full height of the screen.  This works like closing the
                current window and then creating another one with
                ":vert topleft split", except that the current window contents
                is used for the new window.
                {not available when compiled without the |+vertsplit| feature}

                                                CTRL-W_L
CTRL-W L        Move the current window to be at the far right, using the full
                height of the screen.  This works like closing the
                current window and then creating another one with
                ":vert botright split", except that the current window
                contents is used for the new window.
                {not available when compiled without the |+vertsplit| feature}
```

Note that the `H` is a capital here, the lowercase `h` simply moves the cursor to the other window instead of moving the window itself.